# Does Archon Mode count for any Multiplayer achievements?

Tags: starcraft-2

Archon Mode in Legacy of the Void allows two players to team up and control one base.  It shows up under the Unranked/Ranked Multiplayer modes and even has it's own ladder.  However, it seems games won in this mode don't count towards any 1v1 Unranked/Ranked achievements.

Does Archon Mode count for any multiplayer achievements?  Would winning a match grant credit towards the 1000 wins under Team Unranked/Ranked?

Comment: As far as I know, no. But I'm not completely sure about it, as I don't have the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, no.

I suspect blizzard put off achievements for archon mode for some reason, and therefore will probably release archon specific achievements in the future.

Comment: Patch 3.2.0 also brought the following bugfix: *Archon vs. AI games no longer award 2v2 Versus AI achievements.* So yeah, not awarding team achievements is deliberate.